# Cambiar color de tarjetas cuando haga click en javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, eventos, div

el problema que quiero solucionar es el siguiente:

Tengo un div con un id llamado "grupo"(seria el contenedor padre) y dentro tengo tres divs mas que son tarjetas de color gris, cada uno de esos divs tienen un id, ejemplo, el primero tiene "tarjeta1" y asi con los demas.

Lo que quiero hacer mediante el dom de javascript es que, por ejemplo,al hacer click en la primer tarjeta se ponga roja cuando clickeo la segunda se ponga violeta y que la anterior vuelva a estar gris,asi con todas

Podria hacer esto iterando al div "grupo" y segun los id de sus hijos,cambiarlos a un  color diferente?

Como hago esto?

Comment: Agrega tu trabajo del evento click y tu HTML para darte una respuesta

Comment: Buenas noches, sería recomendable que leas [ask], para que podamos ayudarte, para evitar votos negativos y el posible cierre de tu pregunta. 
En general lo ideal es que envíes lo que  se conoce como código mínimo verificable, es decir lo mínimo necesario para poder realizar las pruebas pertinentes, identificar el error y poder ayudarte en el menor tiempo posible.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. [es.so] no es un servicio de código. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Con  document.querySelectorAll obtienes una lista de elementos y luego con la función forEach iteras sobre ellos, tal cual como el ejemplo que te he puesto

```js
const COLOR_DEFAULT = "gray";
function chagecolor(elemento, color){
  chageTodosColor();
  elemento.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
function chageTodosColor(){
 document.querySelectorAll("#grupo > div").forEach(e =>{
   e.style.backgroundColor = COLOR_DEFAULT;
 });
}
```

```css
#grupo{
  display:flex;
  gap:10px;
}

#grupo > div{
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color:gray;
 transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="grupo">
  <div id="tarjeta1" onclick="chagecolor(this, 'red')"></div>
  <div id="tarjeta2" onclick="chagecolor(this, 'violet')"></div>
  <div id="tarjeta3" onclick="chagecolor(this, 'green')"></div>
</div>
```